# Why do I get garbled output when I decode some HTML entities but not others?

Tags: perl, decode, html-entities

In Perl, I am trying to decode strings which contain numeric HTML entities using [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities). Some entities work, while "newer" entities don't. For example:

```
decode_entities('&#174;');  # returns ® as expected
decode_entities('&#8486;'); # returns â„¦ instead of Ω
decode_entities('&#9733;'); # returns â˜… instead of ★
```

Is there a way to decode these "newer" HTML entities in Perl? In PHP, the `html_entity_decode` function seems to decode all of these entities without any problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decoding works fine. It's how you're outputting them that's wrong. For example, you may have sent the strings to a terminal without encoding them for that terminal first. This is achieved through the `open` pragma in the following program:

```
$ perl -e'
    use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
    use HTML::Entities qw( decode_entities );
    CORE::say decode_entities($_)
       for "&#174;", "&#8486;", "&#9733;";
'
®
Ω
★
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your terminal can handle UTF-8 encoding. It looks like it's having problems with multibyte characters. You can also try to set UTF-8 for STDOUT in case you get wide character warnings.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

print decode_entities('&#174;');  # returns ®
print decode_entities('&#8486;'); # returns Ω
print decode_entities('&#9733;'); # returns ★
```

This gives me the correct/expected results.